# combobox must be autocomplete and allow only seleted value from the list

Tags: c#, .net

I want a combo box functionality like -

The combo box shows items and has auto-complete functionality, as the list of items is very large.

I want the user to be able to select a value from the item list by typing into the box w/ the autocomplete functionality - if a user types something that's not in the list, then an available value is automatically selected.

I do not want to send the wrong text to the database.

This combo box is editable ,auto complete , but not accept the editable value ,user must select in list by typing ....

```
private void FrmGroupCreation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaiCon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connect=new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            //data table for combox type of account 
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *FROM dbo.Type_of_Account",connect);

            DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {
                cbTypeofAccount.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["type_Of_Acct"]);
            }
            //data table for combobox principle account type
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *FROM dbo.Principle_Account", connect);

            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da1.Fill(dt1);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                cbPrinciple_account_type.Items.Add(dt1.Rows[i]["Principle_Account"]);
            }
            //data table for combobox Under the group
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *FROM dbo.Head_group_Account", connect);

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            da2.Fill(dt2);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                cbUnder_the_group.Items.Add(dt2.Rows[i]["Account_name"]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does the code above have to do with your question..? you need to set 2 properties on a combobox that will allow for what you are looking also you need to Bind the combobox to the DataSource `Look at using a BindingList` as well if needed

Answer (score 1):

you have to do the following :

1- instead of doing for loop to fill the combobox set the combobox datasource equal to the data table and set the value member and display member

```
 cbTypeofAccount.DataSource = dt;
 cbTypeofAccount.DisplayMember = "type_Of_Acct";
 cbTypeofAccount.ValueMember = "your table id";
```

2- change the dropdown style for the combobox to make it editable

```
 cbTypeofAccount.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
```

Comment: This doesn't include how one would properly make the ComboBox perform auto-complete.